# Casting ? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> in a generic way

Tags: java, types, jackson

A few things, I'm in a situation where the jackson java library is creating the JavaType of

```
? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
```

as

```
[simple type, class java.lang.Object]
```

This is causing some issues elsewhere in my code. I need it to be resolved as:

```
[map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]]
```

The call to `mapper.constructType` works properly with `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>`. So my question is as follows: What is a generic way of casting `? super someType` to simply `someType`.

Some Additional context.

The code uses reflection and passes both java and kotlin files to this java class. The code looks at the params in certain functions to see what it should pass certain config values as. In this case i need to pass a map. I'll write some toy code below.

handler.java:

```
void storeVales(Method method) {

//for f1: this returns java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
// for f2 we get: ? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
parameterType = getParamType(method);

// For f1 this sets as: [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class // java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]]
// and 
// for f2: [simple type, class java.lang.Object]
JavaType javaType = mapper.constructType(parameterType);
myMap.put(method, javaType);
}


Type getParamType(Method method){

Type[] types = method.getGenericParameterTypes();

for(Type t: types) {

   ParameterizedType paramed = (ParameterizedType) t;

  return parameterized.getActualTypeArguments()[0]

}
```

Let me know if you need more. But `storeVales` does the work here. The function signatures Getting passed are as follows:

From a kotlin file:

```
// this does work in a java file and works properly.
fun f1(p: Consumer<Map<String, String>>)

// this does NOT work. From a kotlin file.
fun f2(p: (Map<String, String>) -> Unit)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, using backticks (`\``) for code as necessary, to make it more clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please add some code examples of what you are trying to achieve.